# is "if I had been" correct in this case?

Tags: british-english, lyrics, interpretation

in The Beatles's when I'm 64 lyric,

teh line tha says:

> If I'd been out till quarter to three
> Would you lock the door?

how come The contraction "I'd" is short for "I had" in this context, if the singer is talking
about a coming age, I mean the future?

shouldn't it be: "If have been out till quarter to three Would you lock the door"?

Comment: "If I have been" is not asking about the future, it's asking about the present.

Comment: No. Your version ungrammatically mixes *Present* Perfect *(**I have been**)* with *Past* *(**would**)*, which should be ***will***.

Comment: @stangdon - But the song is about a hypothetical future. By the OP's logic, it should be "Will you lock the door?" - but pop song lyrics don't have to be logical.

Comment: I don't think it's a hypothetical *future* - it's "timeless", which imho is why it's ***would***. A hypothetical future would be something like *If I go shopping tomorrow, **will** you come with me?* - which *could* also use ***would***, but the actual song lyric wouldn't work with ***will*** because the "timing" is different. Just because other "conditionals" in the song are definitely future (the singer at the time wasn't yet 64, but he's well past that age now! :) doesn't mean this particular line has that attribute. Other lines include ***will** you still love me?*

Comment: ...I also think that the precise meaning of the specific line *If I'd been out till quarter to three* is ambiguous until we see the context of the following line. Which *could* have been *Would you **have locked** the door?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, is "would been out" commonly used?

Comment: There are ***no*** contexts in English where the exact sequence "would been out" could ever validly occur. Are you thinking of ""would have been out"?

Comment: Note that some people are happy to say *If I **would** have been out late, would you let me in?* But I'm not one of them. I accept both the contracted versions *If **I'd** been out late...*, and *If **I'd have** been out late...* as perfectly natural, but if I'm not allowed to have contractions I will say *If **had [have]** been out late...*, and I don;t care how many pedants tell me that ***If I had have been...*** is syntactically invalid. I'd rather have that than uncontracted ***would have***.

Answer (score 0):

> If (I were to come home late, and prior to this) I had been out till quarter to three, would you lock the door?

"Had been" is licensed by the implied moment between being out and the door being locked.